# C# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and I'm stuck on an issue and don't know whether this is the way to solve the issue.

I have a controller with the following action method:

```
[Route("customers/show/{id}")]
public ActionResult Show(int id)
{
    var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    return View(customer);
}
```

The issue is as long as the integer is being sent as parameter then no problem.

For example "/customers/show/123", but If someone try to access like this "/customers/show/12xyz" then it will throw an ugly error like this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Show(Int32)' in 'MyApp.Controllers.CustomersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
> Parameter name: parameters

I want to avoid that application error so I tried solving like this.
Is this the correct ASP.NET MVC way or is there any other smarter way?

```
[Route("customers/show/{id}")]
public ActionResult Show(string id)
{
    int custId = 0;
    int.TryParse(id, out custId);

    var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == custId);
    return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: Use the 1st method. You can update your `web.config` to point to a custom error page, which one depends on the status code. That should solve the issue of it being "ugly" *and* keep you from having to write a bunch of code just to route to a proper page in the event of garbage input.

Comment: Stick to your original code and change your route attribute to `[Route("customers/show/{id:int}")]`

Comment: Show us your route.config, it looks like it's conflicting with the default model binder.

Comment: I did not even see that you did not have an `:int` route constraint in there. Do what @dom stated. In the event there is not a match you will get a 403 (I believe). Again, you can use the web.config to point to some custom error page.

Comment: instead sending user to a custom 403 page, i want the user to be in the same layout page as "/show/" but instead showing the content, it should show an error.

Comment: your error page could share whatever styling you want. you could also use ajax and use the `.error` function to handle displaying error data to the user (what you're describing kind of sounds like wanting to keep the user on the same page and show them error details in which case calling the route via ajax will be more appropriate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to handle those problems.  If someone is going directly to a detail page by bypassing your searching UI, then you can either return a 404 not found page or you could redirect them directly to the search page, depending on your use case.

The reason why you are getting this particular error is that you don't have a type constraint on the route it self.  You really only want to deal with an int.  However, if you put that constraint on there and the value isn't an int, then the generic 404 error handling is going to kick in.  It all depends on what your business requirements are here, so I'll show you a few options:

Handle all details and redirect to search when not found:

```
[Route("customers/show/{id}")]
public ActionResult Show(string id)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(id, out var parsedId)) {
        return Redirect("/customers");  // Or return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // Note: You should really pass your Id into GetCustomers somehow or else it'll pull 
    //everything from your database first and then find the one customer in memory
    var customer = GetCustomers().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == parsedId);

    if (customer == null)
    {
        return Redirect("/customers");  // Or return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

Any non-int will be handled by the generic 404:

```
[Route("customers/show/{id:int}")]
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue) {
            return Redirect("/customers");  // Or return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var customer = GetCustomers().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id.Value);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return Redirect("/customers");  // Or return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[Route("customers/show/{id}")]
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
{
    var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

This way, if there is nothing in the database/file/wherever you're searching for that ID, you return a result to the customer that lets them know this; in this case, an HTTP Error 404: Not Found.

Comment: it wont hit the httpnotfound line as it fails already on the (int id declaration) as its not an id.